# How to implement a new layer over JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, layer

What's the best way to implement a new layer over JavaScript framework (jQuery, Prototype, ...)?

```
+------------+
| JavaScript |
+------------+
|   jQuery   |
+------------+
|  MyLibrary |
+------------+
```

For example...

```
MyLibrary = MyLibrary || {};

MyLibrary.animate = function(params) {
   // some code
}

MyLibrary.insert = function(params) {
   // some code
}
```

Execution

```
MyLibrary.animate(params);
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? I don't think I really get it

Comment: What sort of problems are you worried about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just extend jQuery, with [plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), to do what you want. Attempting to wrap the entire jQuery library would seem to be a lot of work just to add some functions.